# Construct the rule in fields extensions

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $f(x) = x^3+6x^2-12x+3$ Show that f(x) is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ . Let $\theta$ be a real root of $f(x)$, which exists due to the intermediate value theorem. $\mathbb Q(\theta)$ consists of elements of the form $a_0+a_1\theta+a_2\theta^2$. Explain how to compute the product in this field and find the product $(7+2\theta+\theta^2)(1+\theta^2)$. Find the inverse of $(7+2\theta+\theta^2)$

My attempt: for prime p =3, f(x) satisfies Eisenten's criterion, hence f(x) is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, hence f(x) is maximal ideal in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Hence $\mathbb Q(x) \approx\mathbb Q[x]/(f(x))$

The multiplication is performed by using the distributive law and then reducing using the rule $\theta^3=-6\theta^2+12\theta-3~~(whence~~~ \theta^4=-6\theta^3+12\theta^2-3\theta)$.

$(7+2\theta+\theta^2)(1+\theta^2)= 7+7\theta^2+2\theta+2\theta^3+\theta^2+\theta^4=\theta^4+2\theta^3+8\theta^2+2\theta+7$.

replace $\theta^4~~and~~\theta^3$ above, I got $44\theta^2-49\theta+19$  as result

But I don't know how to do next. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: You know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)=7+2x+x^2$ are relatively prime polynomials, and that there therefore are polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $Af+Bg=1$ Substitute $x\mapsto\theta$ and get $B(\theta)g(\theta)=1$. You should have seen how to find an $A$ and a $B$ that do the trick for you.

Comment: I did. But all I have to do is long division to get the answer. I do not know how to apply the abstract algebra knowledge here. First, I got f = g*m + r. Next is g = r*n +l and at the end, I got a number and express that number in terms of f and g and do B*g =1 as what you said. However, I had it done based on the knowledge from highschool not from abstract algebra. I am doubt myself when I do not know how to apply the things I am taught in class.

Comment: Well, if you got your $A$ and your $B$, then $B(\theta)$ is the reciprocal of $g(\theta)$, isn’t it?